# Getting page missing when web scraping Morningstar

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am web scraping some financial data from Morningstar using a list of stock symbols and on the 12th symbol, I will get a missing page returned. The page does exist and even if I switch different working symbols into the 12th slot, I get the same page missing. I imagine this is something done by Morningstar. I tried adding time delays to the requests but this didn't work.

What is causing this problem?

```
for symbol in symbols:   
    url_morningstar = 'https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/{}/quote'
    response = requests.get(url_morningstar.format(symbol))
    mySoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    htmlData = mySoup.findAll('span',{'class':'mdc-data-point mdc-data-point--number'})
    while(len(htmlData) == 0):
            print(symbol, ' ---ERROR---')
            print(htmlData)
            #print(response.text)
            response = requests.get(url_morningstar.format(symbol))
            mySoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            htmlData = mySoup.findAll('span',{'class':'mdc-data-point mdc-data-point--number'})
    duration = htmlData[-1].text.strip()
    nav = htmlData[0].text.strip()
```

I tried using a loop to continuously retry the symbol with the missing page but this didn't help.

Edit:

Full Code w symbols

```
    symbols = []
    with open('symbols.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            symbols.append(row[0])
    full_data = []
    for symbol in symbols:   
        print(symbol) 
        url_schwab = 'https://www.schwab.wallst.com/Prospect/Research/MutualFunds/Summary.asp?symbol={}'
        url_morningstar = 'https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/{}/quote'

        response = requests.get(url_schwab.format(symbol))
        mySoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        table = mySoup.find('div',{'id':'detailsWrapper'})
        rows = table.findAll('table',{'class':'tableType1'})
        headers = []
        output = []
        schwab_dict = {}
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find('tbody').find('tr').findAll('td')
            colNames = row.find('tbody').find('tr').findAll('th')
            colNames = [ele.text.strip() for ele in colNames]
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]

            output.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) 
            headers.append([ele for ele in colNames if ele])
        #[['52 Week Range'], ['YTD Return'], ['Gross Expense Ratio'], ['Net Expense Ratio'], ['Tax-Equivalent Yield'], ['30-Day SEC Yield'], ["Distribution Yield], ['Most Recent Distribution'], ['Availability'], ['Manager Tenure']]
        #[['$9.92 - $10.01'], ['0.91%as of 09/02/2021'], ['0.68%'], ['0.68%'], ['--'], ['1.42%'], ['1.65%'], ['$0.0118'], ['Open'], ['2011']]
        headers[1] = ['YTD Return']
        headers[6] = ['Distribution Yield']
        for i in range(len(headers)):
            schwab_dict[headers[i][0]] = output[i][0]


        response = requests.get(url_morningstar.format(symbol))
        mySoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        htmlData = mySoup.findAll('span',{'class':'mdc-data-point mdc-data-point--number'})
        while(len(htmlData) == 0):
            print(symbol, ' ---ERROR---')
            print(htmlData)
            #print(response.text)
            response = requests.get(url_morningstar.format(symbol))
            mySoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            htmlData = mySoup.findAll('span',{'class':'mdc-data-point mdc-data-point--number'})
        duration = htmlData[-1].text.strip()
        nav = htmlData[0].text.strip()

        # extract Duration EXP ratio YTD 2021 SEC Yield Price Last Updated
        results = [duration, schwab_dict['Net Expense Ratio'], schwab_dict['YTD Return'], schwab_dict['30-Day SEC Yield'], nav ]
        full_data.append([results])
    with open('scrappedData.csv', 'x') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.reader(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(full_data)
```

Symbols.csv

```
DLSNX
FFRHX
MWLDX
OSTIX
PRWBX
VBIRX
VSGBX
VFSTX
VFISX
FSTFX
PRFSX
VMLTX 
VWSTX
DODIX
DLTNX
FAGIX
SPHIX
FTHRX
FBNDX
FADMX
FTBFX
LSBRX
MWTRX
RPSIX
VFIIX
VWEHX
VBILX
VFICX
VFITX
VBTLX
FLTMX
PRSMX
VCAIX
VWITX
PRPIX
PRULX
VIPSX
VBLAX
VWESX
VUSTX
FCTFX
FHIGX
FTFMX
FTABX
PRINX
PRFHX
PRTAX
VCITX
VWAHX
VWLTX
LSGLX
RPIBX
VTABX
FCVSX
VWINX
```

Comment: share `symbols` so one can try and reproduce.

Comment: added with full code @balderman

Comment: TMI ... just add a list of 15 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line under your symbols reading code:

```
symbols = []
with open('symbols.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        symbols.append(row[0])
symbols = [s.strip() for s in symbols]
```

I think one of them has an extra space in there.